# ec2 aws only index page is routing, further is error as - URL NOT FOUND

Tags: amazon-ec2

Only index page of aws ec2 instance is routing fine. further pages are not routing at all. I get an error as - **URL NOT FOUND**
It happened after i upgraded from php56 to php70.

**I did restart httpd service**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed.

I needed to edit and modify below in httpd.conf inside etc/conf

```
 AllowOverride All
```

for Directory **/var/www** and Directory **/var/www/html**

Comment: <Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>